# How to select a div based on a checked input box in an adjacent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Given the code segment below, is there a way to write a CSS selector that targets the *div* of `class="item_text"` provided that the checkbox is checked?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <input name="item_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-11">
    <div class="item_text" contenteditable="true">
      To rearrange your list, drag and drop items
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No; CSS cannot (currently) look backwards. You have to make the checkbox either a previous sibling, or a previous sibling of the div's ancestor, so you can use `+` or `~`

Comment: Thanks, took your advice and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in the comments, it's not possible to do this in CSS alone as CSS rules cannot traverse up the DOM.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, you could use that instead to affect the required element when the checkbox state is changed. Try this:

```js
$('.row :checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find('.item_text').toggleClass('foo', this.checked);
});
```

```css
.foo { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <input name="item_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-11">
    <div class="item_text" contenteditable="true">
      To rearrange your list, drag and drop items
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is possible**. I just rearranged the dom slightly then added some css:

```css
input[name=item_checkbox]:checked + div.item_text {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-11">
  <input name="item_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="item_text" contenteditable="true">
      To rearrange your list, drag and drop items
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's only possible with jQuery/javascript as CSS selectors cannot traverse upwards (from child to parent).